# Bootstrap navbar not working as transparent

Tags: navbar

i bought a bootstrap material look template but i did some modifications, but when i submit a transparent css on the top navbar, it is not working i don't know how!, i used the backgroung-image, webkit, and a simple css background transparent but not working, even with !important not successful,i think it has a default color because when i put it a transparent css code it turn into the body default color same as facebook body background color i think it is this one #f4f4f4, any help?

**Html code**

```
<div class="app-content">
        <div class="box">
           <div class="navbar">
<div class="navbar-menu">
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 1</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>

    <!--start content page-->
        <div class="app-content">
                    <div class="box">
                     <div class="navbar">

        <!--start content-->
```

Comment: What is not working.. Please try to create a **[minimal working code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** for these type of questions to understand it better.

Comment: bootstrap has a navbar, i tryied to add transparent color, but when i do that, my navbar keep the color of the body.. i'm new here i don't know what is minimal working code sorry

Comment: take a look at the print screen [link](http://s28.postimg.org/qb2kw9rfx/12394466_562019093951102_1380073394_o.jpg)

Comment: That's why I provided that link above.. **[Click here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**, read it and then paste the required code of try creating the problem in `jsfiddle`.. This is basically `CSS` issue. So no one can help unless you provide some `CSS` and related `html` to replicate the problem..

Comment: thanks anyway, i just solved the problem!! thankss

Comment: Anytime.. Happy Coding.. :)